# Hide Latest product modules in virtue mart page details

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 1.5 and virtuemart 1.1.9 i have included the latest module in virtuemart. It displays the module in product details also i want to show only in virtuemart front page only

How would i hide these modules in product  details page

```
div id="mainBlock">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="shopmodule" />                   
    <jdoc:include type="component" />

</div>
```

Please help me to get out from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out a parameter to identify this view, i.e. view = "product-detail", then

```
if (JRequest::getVar("view","")!=="product-details") {
   ?><jdoc:include type="modules" name="shopmodule" />     <?
}
```